# Different results when using auto as member function argument

Tags: c++, c++14, c++17

I am getting different results when running these two

I am on `GNU/Linux 4.14.67`

These both are ran using `g++ -std=c++14` with/without `-O0` and on `c++17` as well.

Why am I? Why are the outputs different?

First version is:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class foo {
public:
    foo() { }
    foo(const foo& f) { }
    foo& operator=(const foo& f) {
        cout << "foo operator=\n";
        val = 888;
        // Do something important
        return *this;
    }
    int val;
};

int main() {
    foo f1;
    foo f2;
    f1 = f2;

    cout << f1.val << endl;
}
```

The first output is:

```
foo operator=
888
```

---

Second version (only changing `const foo&` to `const auto&` ):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

class foo {
public:
    foo() { }
    foo(const foo& f) { }
    foo& operator=(const auto& f) {
        cout << "foo operator=\n";
        val = 888;
        // Do something important
        return *this;
    }
    int val;
};

int main() {
    foo f1;
    foo f2;
    f1 = f2;

    cout << f1.val << endl;
}
```

The second output is:

```
0
```

Comment: Maybe your forgot "return *this" at the end of op=(...) ?

Comment: I thought so too, but it was a copy and paste error. Good catch

Comment: Not only "*this" but "return *this;"

Comment: _"Why am I?"_ Hard to tell, very philosophical question. Some say _"I am thinking, thus I be (am)"_

Comment: "Why am I?" cogito ergo sum?

Comment: Thank you guys, but Why am I?

Comment: Tack `-pedantic` onto the command line and you may get an interesting surprise.

Comment: @Swordfish Watchworthy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=29pPZQ77cmI

Comment: @Seoul _"Thank you guys, but Why am I?"_ Well, we posted these comments because that's the completely wrong question regarding what's wrong with the code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Haha, well, when a bomb starts to speak of itself in the 3rd person one should get worried ;)

Comment: @Swordfish Same applies to politicians starting to talk about themselves in 3rd person. The difference is quite narrow :3

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Is it kind of allowed to overtake the comments of an off-topic question for small talk? should it be tagged `smalltalk` then? Qs over Qs ;)

Comment: @Swordfish There are better rooms ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This:

```
foo& operator=(const auto& f);
```

will not be standard C++ code until C++20. But gcc has allowed it for quite some time, and what it means is:

```
template <typename _T>
foo& operator=(const _T& f);
```

In other words, this is an assignment operator template. It is *not* a copy assignment operator. That must be a non-template. Since you did not provide a copy assignment operator, the compiler happily generates one for you. In your first code example, you provided your own copy assignment operator.

When you write:

```
f1 = f2;
```

In your first example, that expression has one candidate: the copy assignment operator that you wrote. In the second example, there are *two* candidates: your assignment operator template and the copy assignment operator synthesized by the compiler. The compiler's is a better match (non-template beats template), so it gets called - not yours.

Comment: You might want to mention P1141 @chris digged out.